# Python Basemap does not show the proper plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-basemap

I need to plot some data over a map of the city of Amsterdam, but I can't get Basemap to display the proper plot.  With the code below, all I get is an empty plot and I don't know how to get the map to display.

My code is below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#Create a map around Amsterdam
#http://www.latlong.net/
#Upper Right Corner 52.4268763,5.2415393
#Lower Left Corner 52.3303609,4.6992733

#fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m = Basemap(projection='merc', 
        llcrnrlat=52.3303609,urcrnrlat=52.4268763,
        llcrnrlon=4.6992733, urcrnrlon=5.2415393,
        resolution='c')

m.fillcontinents()
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary()
plt.show()
```

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: You are missing the actual plot command -- where should the actual data for your map come from?

Comment: @Thomas I guess he means the coastlines which are not shown. Additional data must of course be drawn seperately.

Answer (score 2):

The resolution you chose for the basemap, `resolution='c'` is "coarse", meaning that detailed coastlines will not be shown. You can use any of the other possible resolutions

```
l (low), i (intermediate), h (high), f (full)
```

Example:

`resolution="l"`:
[image]

`resolution="i"`:
[image]

`resolution="h"`:
[image]

`resolution="f"`:
[image]

Code to reproduce:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='merc', 
        llcrnrlat=52.3303609,urcrnrlat=52.4268763,
        llcrnrlon=4.6992733, urcrnrlon=5.2415393,
        resolution="f")

m.fillcontinents(color='bisque')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='lightcyan')

plt.show()
```